# Yii Framework - Twiiter Bootstrap TbMenu in Navbar options

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm beginning to work on Yii and PHP and am using this [Twitter Bootstrap by cniska.net](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/)
and am able to make it work.

However I'm finding some difficulties in making it work the way I want to. And have not found anything useful in the docs, although I might have missed something.

I have the *navbar* like this:

```
      $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar', array(
          'brand'=>'XPTO',
          'brandUrl'=>'#',
          'fixed' => 'top',
          'collapse'=>true, // requires bootstrap-responsive.css
          'items'=>array(
              array(
                  'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
                  'items'=>array(
                      array('label'=>'1st Link', 'url'=>'#', 'active'=>true),
                      array('label'=>'2nd Link', 'url'=>'#'),
                      array('label'=>'3rd Link', 'url'=>'#'),
                      array('label'=>'4thLink', 'url'=>'#'),
                  ),
              ),
(..)
```

**So, to my first of 2 questions:**

Underneath `'brand'=>'XPTO'`, is it possible to enter a path to an image? For example the logo? I know I can try to enter an image path but how about images alongside each other? (this would avoid me creating and image containing the 2).

**Secondly:**

I want to manipulate and add page movement in my layout according to the link I click, therefore, *I would like to add the **'id'** attribute to each **'li'**, ***so the final result would be like***:

`<li class="active" id="xyz"><a href="#"> Link Text </a></li>`

I have tried

`array('label'=>'2nd Link', 'url'=>'#', 'id'=>'xyz'),`

and

`array('label'=>'2nd Link', 'url'=>'#', 'htmlOptions'=>array(
                          'id'=>'xyz'),),`

But with no success.

Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the image to work just embed an image in the brand name like so:

```
'brand'=>'<img src="path_to_img.jpg"/>"
```

As for your second question, I just spend 20 minutes scouring the source and [found](https://bitbucket.org/Crisu83/yii-bootstrap/src/a4dff3c27389/widgets/TbBaseMenu.php?at=default#cl-54) out it is called `'itemOptions'` not `'htmlOptions'` when an item has `htmlOptions`. So to add an id use:

```
array('label'=>'First Link', 'url'=>"#", 'itemOptions'=>array('id' => 'xyz'))
```

Comment: You could use css to display your logo.

Comment: sorry for my complete ignorance, but why put the logo in css? if you need to be able to change it later, wouldn't you just put it in a variable (e.g. in your config file in Yii's case).

Comment: just did some research and I know this is a hot debate, but I am going to have to agree with [this guy](http://csswizardry.com/2010/10/your-logo-is-an-image-not-a-h1/). Your logo is an image, not a <h1>.

Comment: I didn't say "you must", but "you could" :) there is no definitive answer to this kind of debate...

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, your solution worked flawlessly, I guess I did miss something in the docs after all :)    Marked as accepted, thanks again.

Comment: @silver no worries and no you didn't miss it in the docs, I couldn't find it in the docs, I had to browse the source and see how each item was handled! Maybe you could log an issue  with yii-bootstrap [about it](https://bitbucket.org/Crisu83/yii-bootstrap/).

Comment: @silver [just created one myself](https://bitbucket.org/Crisu83/yii-bootstrap/issue/240/add-itemoptions-to-the-docs). Only about the `itemOptions` part, not about the html in the brand text as I think that was more obvious.

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks. To familiarised users of the extension I guess it could be obvious, but to beginners like me I think it will help a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

In Yiistrap some properties have changed.

There you should use

```
'brandLabel' => CHtml::image(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl() . '/images/logo.png', 'Logo', array('width' => '37', 'height' => '37')),

'brandUrl' => 'http://www.someurl.com',
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of brandLabel for the image just use brand..